# I tried to use stm32F407 timer function but it doesn't work,

Tags: stm32f4

I tried to use the upcounting function using timer 6 but it doesn't work.

Next is my code

```
void TIMER6_Init(void) //Timer 6 : UP counting mode
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= 0x10;   // RCC_APB1ENR TIMER6 Enable

    // Setting CR1 : 0x0000 
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(1<<4);  // DIR=0(Up counter)
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(1<<1);   // UDIS=0(Update event Enabled): By one of following events
                            //  Counter Overflow/Underflow, 
                            //  Setting the UG bit Set,
                            //  Update Generation through the slave mode controller 
                            // UDIS=1 : Only Update event Enabled by  Counter Overflow/Underflow,
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(1<<2);   // URS=0(Update Request Source  Selection):  By one of following events
                            //  Counter Overflow/Underflow, 
                            // Setting the UG bit Set,
                            //  Update Generation through the slave mode controller 
                            // URS=1 : Only Update Interrupt generated  By  Counter Overflow/Underflow,
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(1<<3);   // OPM=0(The counter is NOT stopped at update event) (reset state)
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(1<<7);   // ARPE=0(ARR is NOT buffered) (reset state)
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(3<<8);   // CKD(Clock division)=00(reset state)
    TIM6->CR1 &= ~(3<<5);   // CMS(Center-aligned mode Sel)=00 (Edge-aligned mode) (reset state)
                            // Center-aligned mode: The counter counts UP and DOWN alternatively

    // Deciding the Period// 
    TIM6->PSC = 1680-1; // Prescaler 84,000,000Hz/1680 = 50,000 HZ (0.02ms)  (1~65536)
    TIM6->ARR = 5000-1; // Auto reload  100ms/ 0.02ms = 5000

    // Clear the Counter
    TIM6->EGR |= (1<<0);    // UG(Update generation)=1 
                        // Re-initialize the counter(CNT=0) & generates an update of registers   

    // Setting an UI(UEV) Interrupt 
    NVIC->ISER[1] |= (1<<(54-32)); // Enable Timer6 global Interrupt
    TIM6->DIER |= (1<<0);   // Enable the Tim6 Update interrupt
    TIM6->CR1 |= (1<<0);    // Enable the Tim6 Counter (clock enable)   
}
```

I checked the data sheet and checked the register, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you troubleshoot it? Have you verified that all registers, that you configure, contain expected values?